# Does my reasoning about the first emergence of proteins make any sense?

Tags: proteins, amino-acids, ribosome

In order to make proteins, a cell uses [ribosomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosome), which itself is a structure made out of proteins. The *first* ribosome couldn't have been created with the help of ribosomes though, as the ribosomes weren't there yet! So where did the *first* proteins came from? *Before* the advent of ribosomes, which, when they arrived on the scene (in some primitive form), subsequently could be used to make increasingly complex proteins.

> In prokaryotes, ribosomes are roughly 40 percent protein and 60 percent rRNA. In eukaryotes, ribosomes are about half protein and half rRNA. Ribosomes are usually made up of three or four rRNA molecules and anywhere from about 40 to 80 different ribosomal proteins.

Amino acids were abundantly present though before ribosomes came into existence. Most of them were left-handed as is life itself (look at the Softenon babies). You can compare this with the matter-antimatter problem in physics (which is not really a problem in my theory, but I won't bother you with that sh*t). A scenario to achieve is easy to come up with.
While competing-self-replicating molecules were present too, they could make good use of them. A rudimentary ribosome emerged (with earlier formed proteins, by accidentally combined amino acids so these proteins came first, actually).
Behold the creation of life! Once started life exploded, leading to us (some say that there is some kind of hyper evolution going on: the rise of the robots with no ticker, no tears, no feelings but a high calculating power).

Is my reasoning reasonable?

Comment: You raised what appears to be a similar point four years ago: [Was there originally a non-ribosomal way of synthesizing proteins?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/43111/was-there-originally-a-non-ribosomal-way-of-synthesizing-proteins). I am not sure what your actual question is this time. You do not seem to elaborate on your title and just state that proteins could have been formed from amino acids.

Comment: I'm asking now if they could have emerged by accident, just as amino acids did. Ain't it probable that in a soup full of amino acids these amino acids will react with each other to form a big collection of protein?

Comment: Before the question can be addressed I think you need to clarify or revise the statement “:…proteins, one of which could have been primordial life”. How can a protein be life?

Comment: @user1136 You can reduce and reduce, so the final question is: where did it all come from? Where there rishons, curved spacetime, inflation, singularities first? Where did they come from? Why is there anything at all? Why isn't there nothing?

Comment: If you wait long enough, amino-acids will combine to get the right proteins. Self-replicating molecules can use them.

Comment: @user1136 The answer can be connected with the fact that Nature (in physics) is left-handed. Only left-handed neutrinos exist. But I question this. It could be that the asymmetry originated just by accident. There are many scenarios to make this happen. Right hands don't fit in lefthand gloves.

Comment: Fred Hoyle thinks that matter is continuously created and the Universe is eternal, so no need for a cause. Panspermia, hmmmm....I would like to live there for certain! Maybe...

Comment: @user1136 You can see it as how the asymmetry between matter and anti-matter occurs in the early Universe,. For sure there is a similar mechanism is at work. between left and right-handed molecules of life.

Comment: Don't you mean "Lucifer's Legacy"?

Comment: why would proteins form without ribosomes?

Comment: @John Wasn't there an abundance of amino acids, prior to life? Amino acids were formed in a lab once. Why **shouldn't** proteins form?

Comment: Now you have changed your question to the merely asking whether a theory you propose is reasonable your question is clearly off-topic for this list and I have voted to close it on this basis.

Comment: @David Fair enough. But why am I not allowed to ask questions anymore? I did edit my questions, so is there still a reason for not being allowed to ask a question?

Comment: If you are being prevented from asking questions this must be a decision of one of the moderators. I am not a mod, just a list member able to cast a vote. You can ask on meta.

Comment: @David Good suggestion! Thanx. ;-}

Comment: I would also say that your "question",  though not a question, could be posted as your own answer to your original question. To amplify the reason I think it is not a question in terms of SE Biology, I would say that it comes in this category of [subjective questions of the sort "…am I right?"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As their name suggests, the majority of a ribosome's structure and function come from ribonucleic acid (RNA), not protein. While ribosomes are about 35%-40% protein on average, a majority of ribosomal proteins are [not essential](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/13413232_Characterization_of_functionally_active_subribosomal_particles_from_Thermus_aquaticus) for the catalytic functions of the ribosome, and none are in direct contact with the [catalytic reaction site](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/289/5481/920.abstract) where peptide bonds are formed. Thus, it's hypothesized that the earliest ribosome analogs consisted [entirely of RNA](https://www.weizmann.ac.il/sb/faculty_pages/Yonath/Davidovich-2009RM-OURS.pdf) in what some might consider a pre-biotic RNA world.

In this ["RNA World"](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/ap-biology/natural-selection/origins-of-life-on-earth/a/rna-world) framework, it is posited that other macromolecular structures, like proteins, DNA, and lipid membranes all arose after the existence of some primitive form of self-replicating RNA molecule.

References:

Khaitovich, Philipp, et al. "Characterization of functionally active subribosomal particles from Thermus aquaticus." Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 96.1 (1999): 85-90.

Nissen P, Hansen J, Ban N, Moore PB, Steitz TA. The structural basis of ribosome activity in peptide bond synthesis. Science. 2000;289(5481):920-930. doi:10.1126/science.289.5481.920

Davidovich, Chen, et al. "The evolving ribosome: from non-coded peptide bond formation to sophisticated translation machinery." Research in Microbiology 160 (2009): 487e492.

Comment: I think you will find a similar RNA world answer to the poster’s previous question. This present question is either a duplicate, and should be ignored, or deserves an answer either criticising the poster’s proposal or explaining the views of those who have considered the nature of early proteins. You may not be aware that there are some eminent scientists that argue against the RNA world, and even if you accept it there are problems about the appearance of proteins.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that the prebiotic world consisted of lf-replicating molecules. These molecules slowly merged with proteins to make ribosomes fit for producing proteins. Life got started!

Comment: Bacterial ribosomes stripped of their proteins still function. they are slower, more error prone, and breakdown faster but they still function. proteins are not needed for the creation of proteins. http://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:408601/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: I edited fro upvoting so I could upvote and accept.